# How can i give python in pycharm permission to all files. Im on mac

Tags: python-3.x, tesseract, permission-denied

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/Users/luksu/wwApp/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytesseract/__init__.py'


img = Image.open("test.jpeg")
print(img)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print('Image text:', text)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/luksu/wwApp/Build/textRead.py", line 11, in <module>
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/luksu/wwApp/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 423, in image_to_string
    return {
           ^
  File "/Users/luksu/wwApp/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 426, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/luksu/wwApp/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 288, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/luksu/wwApp/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 255, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1901, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/luksu/wwApp/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytesseract/__init__.py'
```

Ive tried just about everything to get rid of it but nothing so far has worked, im on mac and am new to python and coding in general so this is the first time ive encountered this kind of problem, i didnt find a working answer anywhere so just created my own post.

Comment: How do you understand `full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable` in pytesseract **[Usage example][1]** 


  [1]: https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

Comment: yeah i used the wrong path, the one in the post probably wouldve worked on pc, but as i am on mac i was refrencing a wrong version of tesseract i had downloaded, i had to find "/opt/homebrew/bin/tesseract" this instead